# Calculate conversion rate on events data Elasticsearch aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

Is there an easy way to calculate a conversion rate with aggregations in elasticsearch?

I have some events data like:

```
{"uuid": "a92405ef-9632-44ce-9cb3-0ae83e434fe9", 
 "created_at": "2015-10-26T21:58:23.132923+00:00",
 "has_data": true, ...}

{"uuid": "4a342de5-4047-4897-8f30-f60c64def839", 
 "created_at": "2015-10-26T21:57:43.985108+00:00",
 "has_data": true, ...}

{"uuid": "47d6add8-003d-4c67-8e9f-1712999b4f15", 
 "created_at": "2015-10-26T21:51:11.062669+00:00",
 "has_data": false, ...}

{"uuid": "a92405ef-9632-44ce-9cb3-0ae83e434fe9", 
 "created_at": "2015-10-26T21:44:17.121071+00:00",
 "has_data": false, ...}
```

And I need to calculate the unique count of **uuid**s that have the **has_data** flag set to true but it was previous(in time, in another document) set to false or the other way around.
For above example the my expected result should be **1**. Only "a92405ef-9632-44ce-9cb3-0ae83e434fe9" is in two documents and has both **true** and **false** "has_data".

Until now i've aggregated on terms **uuid** with size and cardinality on "has_data" and moving on from here.

```
"aggs": {
  "2": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "uuid",
      "size": 0,
    },
    "aggs": {
      "1": {
        "cardinality": {
          "field": "has_data"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this is ... dummy. And no good with millions of events and several thousands of **uuid**s.

I assume I should go with [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). But I can't wrap my head on it. Is it possible to that?
Can someone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has the ingredients for the problem we call a "bucket explosion" - see http://www.slideshare.net/NoSQLmatters/entity-centric-indexing-no-sql-dublin#5

Check out the "entity-centric" solution presented here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-can-i-use-aggregations-to-query-distinct-values-across-all-time-grouped-by-first-seen/25482

Comment: I've been thinking on something similar with the "entity-centric" solution but I couldn't name it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, can't you just "invert" the aggregation you posted?

When I created an index (with `"uuid"` set to `"index":"not_analyzed"`)  and added the data you posted, I can run this aggregation:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "has_data_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "has_data"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "has_data_card": {
               "cardinality": {
                  "field": "uuid"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which returns

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "has_data_terms": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "F",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "has_data_card": {
                  "value": 2
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "T",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "has_data_card": {
                  "value": 2
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

So just ignore `"key": "F"`, and `"key": "T"` should give you the count you want. Then just get a full `uuid` count and you should be able to calculate the proportion you want. It should be straightforward to specialize this technique to work for a certain time-period.

Here is the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/993546914daf15e88ac3e1095a9dfed775b0741c

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've updated the question a little bit. I wasn't too clear on the expected value.
For the example data, my expected result should be 1. Only "a92405ef-9632-44ce-9cb3-0ae83e434fe9" is in two documents and has both true and false as "has_data".

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Can you reorganize the way your data is saved? If you're willing to use a parent/child relationship I think I know how to set it up.

Comment: I can't update the structure but I can pre-process the data. The "entity-centric" solution seems a good place to start.